# Minecraft - Piston elevator without Sticky/Slime/Ender Pearls?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I need a vertical elevator that does not use sticky pistons, slime, or ender pearls. I need to go up around 30 blocks with one press of a button or lever. How can this be done?

Comment: What result do you expect? Something fancy with minecarts or boats or maybe even a command block solution?

Comment: Just a simple and/or compact elevator that moves the player up many blocks with a single press. I'd like to not use boats or water, mainly pistons if possible.

Comment: like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obGjqdMOJ9s)?

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft 1.13 (The Underwater Update) added a new feature that makes elevators easier than ever. You don't need pistons, slime, ender pearls, or even redstone!

All you need is water, [soul sand](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Soul_Sand), and [magma blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Magma_Block). Both can be acquired from the nether, and magma blocks now spawn naturally in the oceans. If you have a column of water source blocks (not flowing water blocks - they MUST be a water source block) with soul sand beneath, it'll create a jet of bubbles that pushes you and all other entities upward. Similarly, if you have a column of water source blocks with a magma block at the bottom, it pulls you down. You can tell if they're working because there will be bubble animations inside the water. It also doesn't consume your air meter, so you can hang out in the flooded "elevator shaft" and not drown. [You can learn more about them on the wiki.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bubble_Column) It is now possible to create elevators that have a 1x1 footprint on the ground, and go arbitrarily tall, with no moving parts whatsoever.

If you want to get fancy with redstone, you can use pistons to push magma, soul sand, or another block type under the column to switch whether it goes up, down, or nowhere, but that is beyond the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-QnkMLFr1c)?
It shows you a bunch of good elevators and how to make them. As of the needs you described, I would reccomend looking at the 4th elevator. It uses pistons and redstone, but no sticky pistons or slime.

If you want to look at the showcase and the tutorial and nothing else, you can skip to:

•Showcase: 02:25

•Tutorial:      16:16

Answer (score -1):

Use stairs! When a stair block is pushed under your character, it climbs up if you are in a 1-block space (It does this by pushing you up against the wall) You should have delays as it goes up.

Comment: There are youtube videos on this too.

Comment: but this uses sticky pistons which he doesn't want

Comment: I also heard this method can result in death which in Hardcore to me is a bit scary.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one that uses pistons and redstone, but it does not use any sticky pistons:

You can get even more ideas [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/342189-how-can-i-make-a-redstone-elevator-without-sticky).

I hope I have been helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I have checked out other elevators but I kind of really want a piston elevator. I'm sure one is possible but I haven't really found a way to do a piston elevator without sticky pistons. Do you have any alternative ideas for survival mode?

Comment: Please don't just present options; customize your answer to solve the problem the asker has posed.